# Has any comics version of Ms. Marvel (Kamala Khan) had light-based powers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ms-marvel, ms-marvel-2022

In the Ms. Marvel TV series, Kamala Khan's powers appear to center around the ability to create solid constructs out of light. By contrast, the main 616 version of Kamala Khan has traditionally had the power to stretch her body, along with associated abilities.

Had any version of Kamala Khan (or any related character) previously had abilities similar to those that she displays in the TV series?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't watched the show yet, but it's possible that the power set is based on the comics version of [Monica Rambeau](https://www.marvel.com/characters/monica-rambeau). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monica_Rambeau#Powers_and_abilities), her powers include:

> Among the many energy forms she has assumed and is able to control are
> visible light, cosmic rays, gamma rays, X-rays, ultraviolet radiation,
> electricity, infrared radiation, microwaves, radio waves, and
> neutrinos.

A number of websites, including [Screen Rant](https://screenrant.com/ms-marvel-mcu-comics-powers-changes-differences-explained/) and [GamesRadar](https://www.gamesradar.com/ms-marvel-kamala-khan-mcu-powers-quantum-bands-nega-bands/), have posited that Kamala's bracelets are meant to be Kree Nega-Bands. Although I don't remember the exact powers from the comics, [fandom](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Nega-Bands#Properties) does include Energy Manipulation in the list.

Comment: It could be, but of course Monica Rambeau also exists in the MCU.

Comment: @Adamant She does. But of the two versions we've seen of her, one does not have powers (yet?), and the other's powers seem to be more similar to Capt Marvel rather than Photon.

Answer (score 1):

As Binary, [Carol Danvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carol_Danvers), the original Ms. Marvel, had photonic powers.

> .... As Binary, the character could tap the energy of a "white hole", allowing full control and manipulation of stellar energies, and therefore control over heat, the electromagnetic spectrum and gravity. Light speed travel and the ability to survive in the vacuum of space were also possible.
>
> Although the link to the white hole was eventually severed, Danvers retains her Binary powers on a smaller scale, enabling her to both absorb energy and project it in photonic form....

Comment: Fair enough, although I was specifically asking about Kamala Khan. I will make that more obvious in the title.